# Go reflection + AST = instantiate type from types.Named

Tags: go, reflection

It could be an overcomplication but I wanted to give this a shot, I'd like to create a binary which lists all structs defined in a given (hardcoded) local package and instantiates a type from it.

From the code below (taken from another SO answer) I can get to the AST somehow and list all types as string, which is fair enough however what I'd like to do is to instantiate a new object from the types.TypeName type.

So far I've failed to do so.

```
const loadMode = packages.NeedName |
    packages.NeedFiles |
    packages.NeedCompiledGoFiles |
    packages.NeedImports |
    packages.NeedDeps |
    packages.NeedTypes |
    packages.NeedSyntax |
    packages.NeedTypesInfo

func main() {
    loadConfig := new(packages.Config)
    loadConfig.Mode = loadMode
    loadConfig.Fset = token.NewFileSet()
    pkgs, err := packages.Load(loadConfig, "github.com/me/mymodule/mypackage2")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, pkg := range pkgs {
        for _, syn := range pkg.Syntax {
            for _, dec := range syn.Decls {
                if gen, ok := dec.(*ast.GenDecl); ok && gen.Tok == token.TYPE {
                    // print doc comment of the type
                    fmt.Println(gen.Doc.List[0])
                    for _, spec := range gen.Specs {
                        if ts, ok := spec.(*ast.TypeSpec); ok {
                            obj, ok := pkg.TypesInfo.Defs[ts.Name]
                            if !ok {
                                continue
                            }
                            typeName, ok := obj.(*types.TypeName)
                            if !ok {
                                continue
                            }
                            named, ok := typeName.Type().(*types.Named)
                            if !ok {
                                continue
                            }
                            // print the full name of the type
                            fmt.Println(named)

                            s, ok := named.Underlying().(*types.Struct)
                            if !ok {
                                continue
                            }

                            // print the struct's fields and tags
                            for i := 0; i < s.NumFields(); i++ {
                                idx := fmt.Sprint(i)
                                fmt.Println("s.Field(", idx, ").Name(): ", s.Field(i).Name())
                                fmt.Println("s.Tag(", idx, "): ", s.Tag(i))
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't instantiate objects using `reflect` as the mechanism and `ast` as the source (without your reflect code actually importing the analyzed package, and even then only with a registry). It's basically no different than asking to instantiate a type with `reflect` from a _string_; If you search for _that_ question on SO you'll find many such questions, and all of them answered, essentially, with an emphatic "NO".

Comment: Reflect deals with the runtime of the running program. You cannot use `reflect` to will an object into existence of whose type is not known to the program's runtime. That's just not a thing.

Comment: Reflection and AST can be used together, but only ever in the "other direction". E.g. the reflection code can pass info about a type to the ast code, in hope to extract more information about that type. But you can't have the ast code pass type info to the reflection code to initialize an instance of that type (unless, as mentioned above, the reflection code actually imports the type's package and has some kind of registry).

Comment: Thanks you all, if one of these had been given as an actual answer I'd been certaninly ticked off green